# How to login user from a specific database table of my choice using django

Tags: django

this is a sample code to login user from the database table "auth_user" created by django but how can i choose a table of my choice like the one i created to log user in

```
def login(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        userName = request.POST['userName']
        password = request.POST['password']

        user = auth.authenticate(username=userName, password=password)
        if user is not None:
        auth.login(request, user)
        return redirect("/")
        else:
        messages.info(request, 'Invalid Credentials')
        return redirect ('login')
    else:
        return render(request, 'login.html')
```

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/auth/customizing/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here auth.authenticate is suitable for login. Here is the entry through the same model, in which case the If you want to create a custom login , I recommend to watch this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HshbjK1vDtY